# How do I adjust z value?

Tags: smartface.io

I am working in Smartface.io framework, working with labels and repeatboxes. As it stands, I cannot access the repeatbox's onSelectedItem because the labels in each row seems to be in front and thereby blocking the actual repeatbox. Is there a way to send the label to be behind the repeatbox? I've tried adding z : "1" into the lbl, and z : "8" into the repeatBox1 variables. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
var lbl = new SMF.UI.Label({
        top : "0%",
        left : "0%",
        width : "50%",
        height : "100%",
        z-index : "0",
        fillColor : "#FFFFFF",
        textAlignment : SMF.UI.TextAlignment.center
    });

var repeatBox1 = new SMF.UI.RepeatBox({
        width : "90%",
        height : "40%",
        left : "5%",
        top : "10%",
        z : "8",
        showScrollbar : true,
        fillColor : "white",
        backgroundTransparent : true
    });
repeatBox1.dataSource = qq;
repeatBox1.controls.
repeatBox1.onRowRender = function (e) {
    this.controls[0].text = qq[e.rowIndex].users;
};
repeatBox1.onSelectedItem = function (e) {
            //Pages.Page2.show();
    alert("Selected " + (e.rowIndex + 1) + ". row");
};

repeatBox1.onRowDeleting = function (e) {
    if (e.rowIndex === 0) {
        alert("first row is deleted...");
    }
};

repeatBox1.itemTemplate.height = Device.screenHeight / 7;
repeatBox1.itemTemplate.imageFillType = SMF.UI.ImageFillType.stretch;
repeatBox1.itemTemplate.add(lbl);

Pages.Page1.add(repeatBox1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for label to behave like it is behind the repeatbox.
But you can use label's e.rowIndex. When label is touched, it returns e.rowIndex value.

```
var lbl = new SMF.UI.Label({
        top : "0%",
        left : "0%",
        width : "50%",
        height : "100%",
        // z-index : "0",
        fillColor : "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundTransparent : false,
        textAlignment : SMF.UI.TextAlignment.center,
        onTouch : function (e) {
            alert("index: " + e.rowIndex);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I've actually tried that before, however it caused another problem. I am trying to make a selectable list in a repeatbox and having an onTouch function attached to the Labels, I run into the problem of not being able to scroll. (everytime I the listbox, i touch the label and end up activating the onTouch function.  Any other suggestions?